# How can I define an extension to CollectionType so that its methods are available to dictionaries?

Tags: swift

I was recently able to change an extension from:

```
extension Array where Element: Encodable { ... }
```

to:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: Encodable { ... }
```

in order to later be able to apply type constraints with `CollectionType` and `Encodable` in a different extension.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with `Dictionary`, changing:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: Encodable { ... }
```

to:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == (Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: Encodable) { ... }
```

However, the latter appears not to be a valid substitute for the `Dictionary` type, since now methods defined within the extension can't be called on dictionaries.

How can I define an extension to `CollectionType` (or maybe `SequenceType`) so that its methods are available to dictionaries?

---

**Update**

I wanted to note that I've tried adding type constraints as follows, without success:

```
extension CollectionType where Self: protocol<Indexable, SequenceType, DictionaryLiteralConvertible>, Self.Key: protocol<Hashable, StringLiteralConvertible>, Self.Value: Encodable, Self.Generator.Element == (Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: Encodable) { ... }
```

---

**Update 2**

Since user2194039 asked – I'd prefer not to have to do this and keep the extensions to `Array` and `Dictionary`.

However, I also need to write extensions for the `Optional` variants. My understanding is that due to their use of generics, it's not possible to write a type constraint for `Optional` that constrains it to `Array` or `Dictionary`.

Comment: Out of personal curiosity (and in light of your answer), can I ask what benefit you get extending `CollectionType` instead of `Dictionary`, when the constraints on your extension are so deeply tied to the structure of a dictionary? P.S. A genuine question!

Comment: @user2194039 in short, JSON encoding. Please see here for further info: https://github.com/edwardaux/Ogra/pull/1

Comment: @user2194039 I misunderstood your question. As shown in the pull request, I needed to also create extensions for `Optional` and could not use `Array` or `Dictionary` in the type constraints for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for my current use case:

```
extension CollectionType where Self: DictionaryLiteralConvertible, Self.Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Self.Value: Encodable, Generator.Element == (Self.Key, Self.Value) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting your solution did help a lot, I converted your solution to swift 3 but don't know why it was not working for me, so I want to post my solution maybe can help someone else.

```
extension Collection where Self: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral, Self.Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Self.Value: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Iterator.Element == (key: Self.Key, value: Self.Value) { ... }
```

I was also able to constraint the collection to a specific type:

```
extension Collection where Self: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral, Self.Key == String, Self.Value == Array<String>, Iterator.Element == (key: Self.Key, value: Self.Value)
```

The key was `Iterator.Element == (key: Self.Key, value: Self.Value)`

Thanks for your help