# Extending an array of dictionaries using Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, swift2

What is the correct way to constraint this extension? My trials didn't succeed.

For example:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: [T.Key:Self.Value], T: DictionaryLiteralConvertible, T.Key: StringLiteralConvertible, T.Value: Encodable {
```

Comment: This looks quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956520/how-can-i-define-an-extension-to-collectiontype-so-that-its-methods-are-availabl.

Comment: Just so you know OP, the Array's associated type T has been renamed to Element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Xcode 8 beta • Swift 3**

```
protocol Encodable {
    var hashValue: Int { get }
}
extension Int: Encodable { }

extension Collection where Iterator.Element == [String: Encodable] {
    var total: Int {
        return reduce(0) {$0 + $1.values.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.hashValue}}
    }
}

let dictionaries:[[String: Encodable]]  = [["One":1],["Two":2],["Three":3, "Four":4]]

dictionaries.total  // 10
```

---

**Xcode 7.3.1 • Swift 2.2.1**

```
protocol Encodable {
    var hashValue: Int { get }
}

extension Int: Encodable { }

extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == [String: Encodable] {
    var total: Int {
        return reduce(0) {$0 + $1.values.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.hashValue}}
    }
}

let dictionaries:[[String: Encodable]]  = [["One":1],["Two":2],["Three":3, "Four":4]]

dictionaries.total  // 10
```

Comment: Could you please clarify why _ArrayType with an underscore?

Comment: Types with a leading underscore are internal, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/36649246/1187415.