# Implicit public access to (Bool) internal type 'Builtin.Int1': runtime exception if appending instances of 'Int1' to an array

Tags: swift

### Question

- I know I probably shouldn't fiddle around with builtin types, but I'm curious, should the `Builtin.Int1` type really be publicly accessible as below? And if so, how come using it as an array element crashes Swift?

I'm curious as I've never come across say a custom type of my own that I haven't been able to store in an array (but I guess the builtin types are different than those I can construct myself using "public Swift").

I'm using Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.

---

### Details

Looking at the source code for [swift/stdlib/public/core/Bool.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Bool.swift), we notice that we can, implicitly, access the internal type `Builtin.Int1` (1-bit integer), which forms the base for the `Bool` type in Swift.

> ```
> public struct Bool {
>     internal var _value: Builtin.Int1
>
>     // ...
>
> }
>
> extension Bool : Boolean {
>     // ...
>     public func _getBuiltinLogicValue() -> Builtin.Int1 {
>         return _value
>     }
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Hence, using `_getBuiltinLogicValue()`, we can construct a value of type `Builtin.Int1`, and using this, declare an empty array of type `[Builtin.Int1]`.

```
/* public access to _getBuiltinLogicValue() ... */
let bar = false._getBuiltinLogicValue()
print(bar.dynamicType)
    /* '<<<opaque type>>>' */
    /* Alt-click: 'Int1' type */

print(_getBool(bar)) // false, OK

/* construct an empty array of 'Int1':s         */
func foo<T>(val: T, arr: [T] = []) -> [T] {
    return arr
}
var arr = foo(bar)
print(arr.dynamicType)
    /* 'Array<<<<opaque type>>>>' */
    /* Alt-click: '[Int1]' type */
```

If we, however, attempt to add any `Builtint.Int1` elements to this array, Swift crashes (runtime exception)

```
/* however any attempt to fill such an array (or initialize
   one as none-empty) will yield a runtime exception         */
//arr.append(bar)   // runtime error
//let arr2 = [bar]  // runtime error
```

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

I finally note that in the source [swift/stdlib/public/core/Builtin.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Character.swift) it is stated that

> ```
> // Definitions that make elements of Builtin usable in real code
> // without gobs of boilerplate.
> ```

Which possibly suggests that we should be able to use the builtin types as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The moment you called a method with a leading underscore, you're no longer calling a public method. The fact that it has a `public` attribute typically is due to a language limitation that requires it to be that way. Compare this to `_ArrayType`, which is also technically `public`, but only because Swift has no way to hide that implementation detail. You're still not supposed to use it directly. They put underscores on these things for a reason. (I've run into this in my own code. It is often difficult or impossible to create protocol extensions that rely on non-public properties; by the time you're done, many things you wanted to be `private` or `internal` have to be `public` or it won't compile.)

Your original assertion "I probably shouldn't fiddle around with builtin types" is correct at this time. It is possible that in the future, builtins will be made more available. But the fact that you had to trick the compiler into even allowing this through generics should be the answer to your question. No. You shouldn't expect to be able to use builtin types this way.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that the above does not, for some reason, crash for Swift 3.0-dev (IBM Sandbox), but given the numerous commits between 2.2 and 3.0, I wont dwell further into as to why. Regarding the `_ArrayType` example: I've seen some answers here on SO that make use of extensions to this to construct an array extension to a specific type; given the discussion above, such methods should always be avoided?

Comment: Writing extension to `_ArrayType` is relying on an implementation detail. For years, people have swizzled Cocoa objects' internals, called "private" methods, and crawled through view hierarchies to modify internal views, but all these techniques are dangerous and fragile, and you certainly shouldn't be surprised when they stop working. Same story for `_ArrayType`. Might work for a specific case (after all, it's all just code); but you're playing outside the API.